# How to change particular cells color using css in Ext.ux.touchcalendar in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I have implemented calendar using Ext.ux.touchcalendar  https://github.com/SwarmOnline/Ext.ux.TouchCalendar  .I want to change some cells color to green and some cells to red and some cells to blue Can anybody tell how to do?

When i trid to add the below css in skin.css

```
.touch-calendar-view table.day tr :nth-child(3) td:nth-child(5).time-block  { /* Selects third row, then select fifth cell. */
   background-color: green!important;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar cells are divided into multiple table cells in multiple table rows.

You can target a certain element by using `nth-child` for both the table row and the containing table cell. Below code is a template, it is better to append some classes instead of tr and td so that it does not affect other tables.

```
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(5) { /* Selects third row, then select fifth cell. */
  background: lightblue;
}
```

**Example output:**

[image]

Comment: Post the whole code you are working on as an edit to the question or create a demo of it using CodePen or JSfiddle please.

Comment: I have edited the question .Can u check this line  .touch-calendar-view table.day tr :nth-child(3) td:nth-child(5).time-block  { /* Selects third row, then select fifth cell. */
   background-color: green!important;
}

Comment: Since you marked my answer as the solution, can I assume it worked now for you? :)

Comment: yes but i haven given like this.touch-calendar-view tbody tr:nth-child(1)  td:nth-child(3)

Comment: Yes it depends on the classes of the code you are using. This answer was a template.